# Django: Table Doesn't exist after shifting MySQL db to server MySQL

Tags: mysql

**Summary**: After uploading mysql "site_dump.sql" into server MySQL, and applying proper settings to point to database, I get error 'Table doesn't exist'

**Error Details:** ProgrammingError: (1146, "Table 'evaluation.Evaluator_skill' doesn't exist")

**Observations**: Only *User* table is showing all the data I had. All other tables are throwing the same error . If I login to MySQL shell, use that new db, and see table data, all the tables and their data is present.

**What I did exactly:**

- On my local PC, took a sql dump like this:

  **mysqldump -u root -p --databases db_name > mysite_26_11_2018.sql**
- Copied this file into server.
- Launched MySQL shell on server using root username and created a new db:

  **mysql>create database db_server;**
- Then on prompt uploaded the copied db like this:

  **mysql -u root -p db_server < mysite_26_11_2018.sql**
- Again logged-in to mysql, and execute these steps:

  mysql>create user server_admin identified by 'admin_password';

  mysql>grant all on db_server.* to 'server_admin'@'%';

  mysql>flush privileges;

**What I tried:** 
 - 1) Ran makemigrations amd migrate, but no changes .

2) Checked using MySQL shell that all data is present in t he db .

3) Checked using django shell that User data is all present but all other tables give the same error.

Comment: This doesnt sound like a django issue, this sounds like a mysql dump/import issue -- i suggest you remove the `django` tag and you'll probably get the help you need. PS. django migrations are not magical -- it looks a at a table called `django_migrations` and if the name of the migration is there django considers it applied (it does NOT scan your database schema and compares it and ... no. simply no.). Your issue sounds to me like you failed to dump all the tables needed.

Comment: An alternative is to use Workbench which will create sql file for each table. you can then manually import failed ones (referential issues etc.)

Comment: @JavierBuzzi  Thanks for your reply. Il remove the tag. But, I can already see in MySQL new db that all tables with their data are present. Nothing is missing. Il try to repeat the DB migration steps again .

Comment: I found something. Error says "evaluation.Evaluator_modelname". But in the db file, i see table names as "evaluator_modelname". @JavierBuzzi .....you were right...I think this blunder happens while dumping SQL...Now to correct this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally solved it . The issue was , all tables were auto lower cased while creating a dump file. I had to hand alter every table name and then it all worked fine.

```
ALTER TABLE oldtable RENAME TO Oldtable;
```

Comment: Glad you found it ;)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem when I deployed my Django Project from Win10 to the Ubuntu server.
In my case, the problem is caused by different case sensitive of Mysql tables on Windows and Linux. On Linux, the names of the tables are case-sensitive, but on Windows, they are not.
So my resolution is to define specific table names in the Django model code file.

```
class TestModel(models.Model):
    pass
    class Meta:
        db_table = 'test_table'
```